# Scraping an onclick value in BeautifulSoup in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

For class, we've been asked to scrape the North Koren News Agency's website: http://kcna.kp/kcna.user.home.retrieveHomeInfoList.kcmsf

The question asks to scrape the `onclick` values for the website. I've tried solving this in two different ways: by navigating the DOM tree. And by building a regex within a lop to systematically pull them out. I've failed on both counts.

Attempt1:

```
onclick_soup = soup_doc.find_all('a', class_='titlebet')[0]
onclick_soup
```

Output:

```
<a class="titlebet" href="#this" onclick='fn_showArticle("AR0140322",
"", "NT00", "L")'>경애하는 최고령도자 <nobr><strong><font
style="font-size:10pt;">김정은</font></strong></nobr>동지께서 라오스인민혁명당 중앙위원회
총비서인 라오스인민민주주의공화국 주석에게 축전을 보내시였다</a>
```

Attempt2:

```
regex_for_onclick_soup = r"onclick='(.*?)\(" onclick_value_soup =
soup_doc.find_all('a', class_='titlebet') for onclick_value in
onclick_value_soup: value =
re.findall(regex_for_onclick_value,onclick_value) print(onclick_value)
```

Attempt2 results in a `TypeError`

I'm doing this in pandas. Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate over every element tag in your html and check for the `onclick` event.

```py
page= requests.get('http://kcna.kp/kcna.user.home.retrieveHomeInfoList.kcmsf')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.find_all():
    on_click = tag.get('onclick')
    if on_click:
        print(on_click)
```

Note that when using `find_all()` whithout any argument it will retrieve every tag. Then we use this tags to search for a `onclick` that is not `None` and print it out.

#### Outputs:

```
fn_convertLanguage('kor')
fn_convertLanguage('eng')
fn_convertLanguage('chn')
fn_convertLanguage('rus')
fn_convertLanguage('spn')
fn_convertLanguage('jpn')
GotoLogin()
register()
evalSearch()
...
```